# Creating new column in Pandas based on values from another column

Tags: python, pandas

The task is the following:

> Add a new column to df called income10. It should contain the same
>   values as income with all 0 values replaced with 1.

I have tried the following code:

```
df['income10'] = np.where(df['income']==0, df['income10'],1)
```

but I keep getting an error:

[image]

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Groger        Just updated post with image of error

Comment: It appears that income is not a valid column name. If you print out df.columns, you should be able to see which columns are available to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a function on each value in your column:

```
df["a"] = df.a.apply(lambda x: 1 if x == 0 else x)
```

Comment: He wants the new values assigned to a new column

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reference a column which does not exist yet.

```
df['income10'] = np.where(df['income']==0, ===>**df['income10']**,1)
```

In your np.where, you need to reference the column where the values originate. Try this instead

```
df['income10'] = np.where(df['income']==0, 1, df['income'])
```

Edit: corrected order of arguments

Comment: I think your where is backwards. It should be `df['income10'] = np.where(df['income']==0,1,df['income'])` as it's 1 if True, else `df['income]`

Comment: @DavidBuck The syntax of `np.where` is `np.where(boolArray, trueValues, falseValues)` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

Comment: Yep, and OP says ' 0 values replaced with 1' so when `df['income']==0` is true, it should be 1, otherwise `df['income']`

Comment: @DavidBuck I see my mistake. Thanks for catching it.